# JPA CriteriaBuilder SELECT two Columns WHERE values IN Collection of Tuples

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have a question about JPA CriteriaBuilder.

I have a table with two foreign keys `A_ID` and `B_ID`. Now i want to select all records where the pair of `(A_ID, B_ID)` are in a Set of tuples. Is it possible to build this query with CriteriaBuilder?

In Oracle Database the followed query will work:

```
SELECT a.ID FROM TABLE_NAME a WHERE (a.A_ID, a.B_ID) IN ((123, 21), (423, 32));
```

But i have difficulty to build the where clause with CriteriaBuilder. Does `IN Expression` only work with single value? Or maybe is it possible to do the same thing with subquery?

Comment: Of course IN only works with single values, as per the JPQL BNF http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/jpql.html#bnf

Comment: Thanks, would you give a suggestion to solve this problem? I don't want to use native query at all.

Comment: That IN you quote is the exact same as "WHERE (a.A_ID = 123 AND a.B_ID = 21) OR (a.A_ID = 423 AND a.B_ID = 32)". You can use Criteria if you need more than that simple example and generate "n" tuples.

Comment: Yes it's just a simple example. In real life the parameter can be a Set<CustomTuple<Long, Long>> or two of Set<Long> with alot of Objects. I can maybe use JPQL with a generated string behind where clause but it's just ugly? And what is about performance?

Comment: what about performance? Why not consult your DB? Usually an IN is converted to that in the query plan IMHO, but then you can inspect that manually in the RDBMS for any query

Comment: Today i could test the performance and it was very poor. Oracle 10g need about 10 seconds for a query with 5700 Tuples. If i devide the list of tuples to smaller lists for more selects and then combine the result lists together then the time of execution varies depends on size of devided lists (sometimes besser performance and sometimes worse). But anyway it took alot of time. Maybe does someone have sometime a better solution.